# How to extract items from list and use them as names of new sets of list?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list called "Collection":

```
Collection = ['a','b','c','d']
```

From this list, I would like to create 4 lists:

```
a_list = []
b_list = []
c_list = []
d_list = []
```

Is there a way to do something like the followings to create the above 4 lists?

```
for item in Collection:
    item_list = []
```

Comment: Use *another container* like a `dict`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: thank you for your quick response.. could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Use a `dict`, don't dynamically name variables. You'll end up using the global name-space dictionary, but then, you might as well just use your own dictionary.

Comment: There are ways to do what you want, but I would urge you just to use a dictionary if you want to relate a string to a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, it is considered a bad idea to make variable names dynamic, which is why there is no *easy* way to do it in Python (and other languages as well).

The closest thing you can get is by using dictionaries:

```
c = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
dict_with_new_lists = {item: [] for item in c}
# Now contains: {'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': [], 'd': []}
```

Now to access your lists:

```
some_variable = 'a'
print(dict_with_new_lists[some_variable])
# etc...
```

Comment: defaultdict is better !

Comment: @anati only if you want the `defaultdict` behavior.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't believe it is applicable to write create dictionary manually like in answer, suppose the list is large.

Comment: @anati it is totally possibly to do it programmatically.

Comment: Remolten and @juanpa.arrivillaga: thank you for your help.. i won't do it dynamically then. My problem is that the number of items in `c = ['a','b','c','d',...]` is determined by the users and vary from one user to another. I am still not sure how to generalize the code..

Comment: @Lam use 'defaultdict'

Comment: I have edited my answer to dynamically create the dictionary.

Comment: got it! thank you Remolten and @juanpa.arrivillaga: i want to put a check mark and thumbs up for your answer and comment, but my reputation is too low..

Comment: You can still mark an answer as your solution by clicking the checkmark. This works regardless of your reputation. Voting up is the privilege that is unlocked later.

Comment: @Remolten What is the pythonic way: dict comprehension or defualtdict ?

Comment: Ahh ok.. Done.. I just can't check mark for both..

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is define default dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

collection_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

collection_dict = defaultdict(list)

Collection = ['a','b','c','d']
for elt in Collection:
    collection_dict[elt].append('sample')
print(collection_dict)

> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'d': ['sample'], 'a': ['sample'], 'c':
> ['sample'], 'b': ['sample']})
```

Comment: got it! thank you @anati: i want to put a check mark and thumbs up for your answer and comment, but my reputation is too low..